# python - [tool.poetry] section not found in pyproject.toml when building Singularity Container

Tags: python, python-poetry, singularity-container

I am trying to build a Singularity Container to run on HPC environment. I am using `poetry` to manage python packages.

The contents of my `pyproject.toml` file are as follows:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "haqc"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Vivek Katial <vivekkatial@gmail.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
...
haqc = {path = ".", develop = true}

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Then in my `Singularity` definition file I have the following to get setup with `poetry`:

```bash
%post
  pip install --upgrade pip
  git clone https://<REPO>.git
  cd HAQC
  pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"
  poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
  && poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi
```

Every time I try and build the container I receive the following error, despite the `pyproject.toml` file being present in the directory at build (I `echo`'d an `ls -lhar` to check):

```
  PyProjectException

  [tool.poetry] section not found in /HAQC/pyproject.toml

  at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/core/pyproject/toml.py:56 in poetry_config
      52│     def poetry_config(self):  # type: () -> Optional[TOMLDocument]
      53│         if self._poetry_config is None:
      54│             self._poetry_config = self.data.get("tool", {}).get("poetry")
      55│             if self._poetry_config is None:
    → 56│                 raise PyProjectException(
      57│                     "[tool.poetry] section not found in {}".format(self._file)
      58│                 )
      59│         return self._poetry_config
      60│
```

Comment: if you cat the file what content do you see?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I provided a `.toml` without any package to install in it (due to a wrong `COPY` in my Dockerfile).

Make sure your `pyproject.toml` contains a `[tool.poetry.dependencies]` section.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, in my case I had the following line in my `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock
```

It should be:

```
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./
```